# React/Firebase Google Sign-in Not working, but no errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I've followed this Facebook signin tutorial here - [Website](https://www.menubar.io/firebase-facebook-login-react/), and tried modifying it to make a Google sign-in.

The code I ended up with is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// import provider and auth that we exported from src/client.js
import {provider, auth} from './client';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      user: null
    }
  }

  async login() {
    const result = await auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
    console.log(result);
    this.setState({user: result.user});
  }

  async logout() {
    await auth().signOut()
    this.setState({user: null});
  }
  render() {
    const {user} = this.state
    console.log(this.state.user);
    return(
      <div className="app">
        <p>{user ? `Hi, ${user.displayName}!` : 'Hi!'}</p>
        <button onClick={this.login.bind(this)}>
          Login with Facebook
        </button>

        <button onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}>
          Logout
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "My Info",
    authDomain: "My Info",
    databaseURL: "My Info",
    projectId: "My Info",
    storageBucket: "My Info",
    messagingSenderId: "My Info"
};


firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const ref = firebase.database().ref()
export const auth = firebase.auth
export const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
```

I don't seem to get any errors int he console and the rest of the code is untouched from the create-react-app. If anyone could help me with setting this up I'd greatly appreciate the help. I'm hoping to integrate this with redux after I'm done, but that's a long ways away sadly.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: The popup for logging in stays white and doesn't change (doing the redirect actually shows me a user selection though), but I have a console log to show user and it's always null or undefined. At the top of the page it should say hi with my name in it { <p>{user ? `Hi, ${user.displayName}!` : 'Hi!'}</p> }

Comment: In the `login` function in your `App` class, `console.log(result)` logs undefined? Hm, try using a promise instead of `async`/`await`. I'm not sure why `async`/`await` would break it but that's the first thing I'd rule out.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new at this. How would I use a promise? Callback?

Comment: The Firebase docs usually use promises in examples. [Here's the guide for setting up auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin). To be clear, I do like async/await but it is *possible* that it's causing an issue here, since Firebase uses a custom promise implementation.

Comment: So I read over the guide, and I truly apologize for my stupidity, but I don't understand what I need to do to my code to get it converted to promises and working. Again I'm sorry!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165800/discussion-between-elad-karni-and-sidney).

Answer (score 0):

Some Improvement according to me

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

    // import provider and auth that we exported from src/client.js
    import {provider, auth} from './client';

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          user: null
        }
       this.login = this.login.bind(this);
       this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
      }

      async login() {
        provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: "select_account" });
        const result = await auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
        console.log(result);
        this.setState({user: result.user});
      }

      async logout() {
        await auth().signOut()
        this.setState({user: null});
      }
      render() {
        const {user} = this.state
        console.log(this.state.user);
        return(
          <div className="app">
            <p>{user ? `Hi, ${user.displayName}!` : 'Hi!'}</p>
            <button onClick={this.login())}>
              Login with Facebook
            </button>

            <button onClick={this.logout()}>
              Logout
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: What's improved and why? A bit of description is always better than having to play "spot the difference" with a large code block